# Running Jest tests on Appveyor from powershell

Tags: reactjs, powershell, jestjs, create-react-app, appveyor

I am trying to run my Jest tests on Appveyor. I am using the asp.net core template for a react app (which uses create-react-app). When I run the tests locally (with `npm run test`) the tests run fine, I see `PASS src\App.test.js` with a run-down of the tests that have passed.

In Appveyor, however, an error is thrown from the console, causing my build to fail. The error message is `PASS src\App.test.js`. So it would seem an error is being emitted from the run somehow, despite the fact it seems to actually be passing. I checked and `$LASTEXITCODE` is `-1`

App.Test.js

`it('Runs tests', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});`

Appveyor.yml

`test_script:
- ps: .\build\appveyor\js-tests.ps1`

.\build\appveyor\js-tests.ps1

`($env:CI = $true) -and (npm run test)`

I'm setting the CI environment as this prevents the tests from using "watch". the js-tests script does some other stuff with sorting file locations and a bit of logging etc, but I don't think that is relevant giving the message comes back as a passed test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Npm sometimes writes normal output to `stdErr`, which custom PowerShell host on AppVeyor treats as error. Solution is to run those tests in CMD. So wrap them int `.cmd` file and run with `- cmd:` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @ilyaf 's answer was to use `jest-silent-reporter`, which does not give an output when tests pass. This works for the same reason ilyaf's answer does, because npm writes output to `stderr`, not writing anything solves it.

to install:
`npm install jest-silent-reporter --save-dev`

in your package.json

`"scripts": {

    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --reporters jest-silent-reporter",
  },`

note i define the reporter here.

I'd also recommend adding a log after calling `npm test` so your logs have some confirmation that the thing has run.